# Server-side timeout issues with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, timeout

I am currently building a rails app, using the devise gem for authentication.

Currently in the app there is only client-side timeout functionality implemented, which I don't feel is a good final solution. Because it doesn't cover the case when a user puts their computer to sleep just for 1 example.

So I wanted to implement the timeout module in devise, however there are several issues I am facing. The issues are because with server-side timeout the user needs to navigate to a different page before they are redirected to the sign in page. And there are a lot of interactions in my app when a user will open a modal in the UI, which will trigger an AJAX call (which will fail if they have been timed out on the server-side).

Here are 2 approaches I have thought of, but I don't see them as good solutions so maybe someone can build on one of these approaches or help point me in a different direction:

1.) In my AJAX requests, add a handler inside the 'error' callback that will tell the user to refresh the page or go to the login page if the error callback returns a 401 Unauthorized response.

Cons: There are a lot of these ajax requests in the app, so there would be a lot of repetitive code and I see this as being difficult to maintain.

2.) Add a click handler to the body and every time it is triggered, send a request to the backend to validate if the user is still logged in. If they aren't redirect the user to the login page.

Cons: Performance issues

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with another developer who helped me come up with a solution to this issue.

With the client-side timeout, I had a countdown timer starting at 15 minutes, which obviously only works if the user's computer is not asleep.

So instead of a countdown timer, I create a new date object, setting the time to 15 minutes in the future (UTC). And then I set an interval which compares the current datetime (UTC) with the future date object and if it has been reach or surpassed it renders a message with a link to the sign in page. When this message is rendered is also makes a call to the backend to kill the user session to cover the case where the user tries to refresh their browser, which would then result in them being sent back to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this from server site.

```
:expire_after: 120.minute
```

in your initializers/session_store.rb, Below example.

```
Tastebook::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                            key: '_tastebook_app_session',
                            expire_after: 120.minute
```

Comment: I don't believe this would solve the issue. For example if a user's computer woke up from being asleep it would appear to them as if they were still logged in unless they refresh the page or navigate to a different page. And if they then thought they were logged in and tried to open one of the modal's nothing would happen because the server call would fail, and it would appear as if the app if frozen which I don't think would be a good experience for the user.

Comment: I know it's been a while since this was posted but I have to ask, why wouldn't this be a solid solution? The scenario that you brought up should be something that is covered by before filters in your controllers so if the user is not logged in, they get redirected the second they try to execute one of those actions. The reason I say this is because I can easily open two tabs, log out of one and then on the other one run into your modal issue because I'm no longer signed in.

Comment: So having the countdown timer covers if the session times out naturally, but if you aren't covering when the user kills the session himself, you're going to run into issues.